# Best way to create a list of lines with different background colours

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to have a list of messages in my application with different levels of priority. Those levels I want to make clear with changing background colors.

I have implemented this already using a `ListViewItem`, but the issue there, is that has to have columns when the `View` property is set to `Details`. Also, I cannot make the columns size with the window I put the `ListView` in.

```
ListViewItem lvi = lvMessages.Items.Add(message);
switch (level) {
  case Level.Warning:
    lvi.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
  break;
  case Level.Error:
    lvi.BackColor = Color.Red;
  break;
}
```

Are there other ways of making a nice, scalable list if lines with differing background colors?

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: Added some code, which works fine, except for the fact that it doesn't scale well. I need to add a `ColumnHeader`, which I do not want.

Comment: Why not using a DataGridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (Remember that this will give you a kick start. There are better ways to implement this.

```
    enum Level
    {
        Warning,
        Error
    }

    class ITemInListView
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
        public Level level { get; set; }
    }
```

Set your ListView properties as:

1. Add a column with empty Text property.
2. Set the View property to Details
3. Set the HeaderStyle property to None.

Then use it as (just an example):

```
    var list = new List<ITemInListView>();
    var item1 = new ITemInListView()
    {
        message = "This is item1",
        level = Level.Warning
    };

    var item2 = new ITemInListView()
    {
        message = "This is item2",
        level = Level.Error
    };

    var item3 = new ITemInListView()
    {
        message = "This is item3",
        level = Level.Error
    };

    var item4 = new ITemInListView()
    {
        message = "This is item4",
        level = Level.Warning
    };

    list.Add(item1);
    list.Add(item2);
    list.Add(item3);
    list.Add(item4);


    //Set the width of the column to be the width of the ListView control so it expands to full size.
    lvMessages.Columns[0].Width = lvMessages.Width;

    foreach (ITemInListView item in list)
    {
        var lvi = lvMessages.Items.Add(item.message);
        switch (item.level)
        {
            case Level.Warning:
                lvi.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                break;
            case Level.Error:
                lvi.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works, and I have it like this now, but it is not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Then you need to use another control or create your own user control to achieve what you want. With the listview, this is the best you can do.